# how can i get the message id from another function

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm coding a bot that give a Muted role to the user when a staff member click the reaction of a specific the message, but i have a problem that i want to get a message id from another function and check if it is has the same id as the message that the staff member has reacted in it.
how can i do that ?

this is my code:

```
class mute(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.has_role("Staff")
    @commands.command()
    async def mute(self,ctx,member:discord.Member=None):
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
        reasons = discord.Embed(title="قم بأختيار سبب الميوت",color=0x00ff00,description="1-\n2-\n3-\n4-")
        reasons.set_footer(text=member,icon_url=member.avatar_url)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=reasons)
        await msg.add_reaction(str("1️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str("2️⃣")) 
        await msg.add_reaction(str("3️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str("4️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str("5️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str("6️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str("7️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str("8️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str("9️⃣"))
        await msg.add_reaction(str(""))

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self,reaction, user):
        if user.id == self.client.user.id:
            return
        if reaction.message.id == self.mute.msg.id:
            print("correct message")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variables inside a function because they are local variables. You could use global variables but that's really expensive and ugly. So what could you do?
You could create an attribute on mute's object and save the messages' object or ID.

An example?

```
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    self.msgs = {}

...
async def mute(self, ctx, ...):
    msg = await ctx.send(...)
    self.msgs[ctx.author] = msg

...
async def on_reaction_add(self, ctx, ...):
    try:
        msg = self.msgs[ctx.author]
    except KeyError:
        return

    if ctx.message.id == msg.id:
        #correct message
```